# how to group uneven data frame by condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am wondering is there a thing with a `unique` or other function/method for pandas to slice a table where I have a pattern:

```
1.0, 2.0, 2.1,
1.0, 2.2, 2.0,
1.0, 2.3, 1.9,
1.5, 2.1, 2.0
1.5, 1.8, 1.9,
...
```

uneven table with 1st column as an indicator of where to group/slice lines.

Loop/ group it for array/list/whatever that contains values of 1.0, 1.5 grouped together
I was trying to get

array1 as:

```
 1.0, 2.0, 2.1
 1.0, 2.2, 2.0
 1.0, 2.3, 1.9
```

array_2

```
 1.5, 2.1, 2.0
 1.5, 1.8, 1.9
```

I tried `first_col = df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()`
but it is not what I would need.

Answer (score 1):

If need loop by groups by first column use:

```
for i, g in df.groupby(df.columns[0]):
     print (g.mean().to_numpy())
```

If need list of DataFrames:

```
L = [g for i, g in df.groupby(df.columns[0])]
```

If need dictionary of DataFrames:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df.columns[0])))
```

EDIT:

Simpliest is new column:

```
df['avg'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

For arrays per groups:

```
for i, g in df.groupby(df.columns[0]):
     print (g.mean().to_numpy())
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is it. Could I `return` or `append` a list/or export it to a file/separate data frame to obtain for each grouped `array` to have one point?
What I mean is:
from ```1.0, 2.0, 2.1
 1.0, 2.2, 2.0
 1.0, 2.3, 1.9```
get 
```1.0, 2.16, 2``` and have it in separate data frame or stored as a separate column

Comment: @JESUS_M - answer was edited.